# Configuration of Hadoop xml file

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

What is the right configuration of **hdfs-site.xml** file while configuring Hadoop.
On all the websites I see this :

```
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

I used the same configuration but was unable to start the datanode.
later I changed the configuration of datanode to

`<name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>`

instead of

`<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>`

and it worked.
which one is right `name.dir` or `data.dir`?

because all the websites say the data.dir but that does not work in my case.
Thanks guys.

Comment: remove the **'s. They don't bold string inside a codeblock !

Answer (score 0):

The options are `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir`. The first defines the directory where namenode information will be held. Second defines where datanode information will be held.

If the node is a namenode, you need the namenode folder configuration. If it's a datanode, you need the datanode folder configuration. If it's a single-node cluster, you need both, as the node acts as both namenode and datanode.

If that doesn't work, what is the error message you get? Have you formatted the namenode?